# How do i resolve these problems for Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Im working on a project, which at first was going well, untill i got to a few specific parts.
I have finished the code and now i have 33+ problems!
Here is the code:

```py
health = 100
location = "Borobudur Temple"

print(
    "As a traveler, you will visit places in Java in order to find the Java Crown."
)
print("You will solve puzzles and go through a series of challenges.")
print("You appear to be heading to the Borobudur Temple.")
print("Lets start with your name. What is it?")

name = input("> ")
print("Hello, " + name + "!")

print("Ready to begin?")
ready = input("> ")

print("Wonderful! Lets begin this journey.")

print(
    "\nAs you walk along the trees around the Borobudur Temple, you see a large bush which is blocking the way."
)
print("Would you like to walk through it, or find another way?")

pathChoice = input("> ").lower()

if pathChoice == "walk through it":
    health -= 5
    print("Health lost: -5, current health:" + str(health) + ".")
    print("Looks like you have accidentally gotten cuts from the thorns. Be careful!\n")
    print("You have now reached the Borobudur Temple, do you wish to enter it?")
    enterChoice = input("> ").lower()

    if enterChoice == "yes":
        print("You have entered the Borobudur Temple. You see a large door with a keyhole. Do you wish to try and open it?")
        openChoice = input("> ").lower()

        if openChoice == "yes":
            print("It seems to be unsuccessful. You need to find another way to open it.")
            print("You have to find a key!")
            print("You notice two paths, one leading left and the other right. Which path do you choose?")
            keyPath = input("> ").lower()

            if keyPath == "left":
                # Puzzles to get key when going left
                print("You have chosen to go left. A genie appears in front of you.")
                print("The genie presents you with a riddle: 'I speak without a mouth and hear without ears. I have no body, but I come alive with the wind. What am I?'")

                answer = input("> ").lower()

                if answer == "echo":
                    print("Congratulations! You have solved the riddle and obtained the key.")

            elif keyPath == "right":
                # Puzzles to get the key when going right
                print("You have chosen to go right. A maze appears in front of you. Navigate through the maze to get the key!")
            else:
                print("Invalid choice for the key path.")

            print("You have obtained the key. Would you like to explore and open the large door?")
            exploreChoice = input("> ").lower()

            if exploreChoice == "yes":
                # Code for exploring further
                print("You decide to explore further within the temple.")
    # Additional exploration code can be added here

    # Maze navigation
    print("After walking through dark corridors and solving intricate puzzles, you find yourself in front of a maze.")
    print("You must navigate through the maze to reach the other side.")
    maze = [
        "##########",
        "#    #   #",
        "###  #   #",
        "#    #####",
        "###      #",
        "##########"
    ]

    def print_maze(maze):
        for row in maze:
            print(row)

    print_maze(maze)

    print("Navigate through the maze using 'w' to move up, 'a' to move left, 's' to move down, and 'd' to move right.")

    current_position = [1, 1]
    max_attempts = 10
    attempts = 0

    while maze[current_position[0]][current_position[1]] != "#":
        move = input("Enter your move (w/a/s/d): ").lower()

        if move == "w":
            if maze[current_position[0]] - 1:
        elif move == "a":
            if maze[current_position[0]][current_position[1] - 1] != "#":
                current_position[1] -= 1
        elif move == "s":
            if maze[current_position[0] + 1][current_position[1]] != "#":
                current_position[0] += 1
        elif move == "d":
            if maze[current_position[0]][current_position[1] + 1] != "#":
                current_position[1] += 1

        print_maze(maze)

    print("Congratulations! You have navigated through the maze and reached the other side.")
    # Final puzzle and Java Crown
    print("You have now entered a hidden secret room within the temple. Among a few statues, there is a mysterious box hanging from above.")
    print("You need to solve the final puzzle to reveal the contents of the box and claim the Java Crown.")

    final_puzzle = input("Final puzzle: What is always in front of you but can't be seen? ")

    if final_puzzle.lower() == "future":
        print("Congratulations! You have solved the final puzzle.")
        print("As you solve the puzzle, the box opens and from within it descends the Java Crown!")
        print("Thank you for playing. You have successfully found the Java Crown and completed the adventure.")
    else:
        print("Incorrect answer. The box remains closed. You need to solve the final puzzle to reveal the Java Crown.")
else:
    # Code for opening the door
    print("You have chosen to open the large door.")
    print("As you open the door, you discover a maze-like passage ahead.")
    print("You must now find your way through the maze to progress further.")
    # Additional code for maze navigation can be added here as shown above
    # End of the game for this path
    print("Thank you for playing. The adventure ends here.")

elif keyPath.lower() == "right":
  # Puzzles to get the key when going right
  print("You have chosen to go right. A maze appears in front of you. Navigate through the maze to get the key!")
else:
  print("Invalid choice for the key path.")

#KEJJJ
else:
print("Incorrect answer. The genie disappears, and you must find another way to get the key.")

    elif enterChoice.lower() == "no":
        print("You have decided to not enter the Borobudur Temple.")
    else:
        print("You have chosen to not enter the Borobudur Temple.")

# Find another way
elif pathChoice.lower() == "find another way":
    print("Wonderful choice. You begin walking towards the temple.\n")
    print("You have now reached the Borobudur Temple, do you wish to enter it?")
    enterChoice = input("> ")

                # enter
                if enterChoice.lower() == "yes":
                    print("You have entered the Borobudur Temple. You see a large door with a keyhole. Do you wish to try and open it?")
                    openChoice = input("> ")
                    # yes
                    if openChoice.lower() == "yes":
                        print("It seems to be unsuccessful. You need to find another way to open it.")
                        print("You have to find a key!")
                        print("You notice two paths, one leading left and the other right. Which path do you choose?")
                        keyPath = input("> ")

                        if keyPath.lower() == "left":
                            # Puzzles to get key when going left
                            print("You have chosen to go left. A genie appears in front of you.")
                            print("The genie presents you with a riddle: 'I speak without a mouth and hear without ears. I have no body, but I come alive with the wind. What am I?'")

                            answer = input("> ")
                            if answer.lower() == "echo":
                                print("Congratulations! You have solved the riddle and obtained the key.")

                        elif keyPath.lower() == "right":
                            # Puzzles to get the key when going right
                            print("You have chosen to go right. A maze appears in front of you. Navigate through the maze to get the key!")
                        else:
                            print("Invalid choice for the key path.")

                        print("You have obtained the key. Would you like to explore and open the large door?")
                        exploreChoice = input("> ")
                        if exploreChoice.lower() == "yes":
                            # Code for exploring further
                            print("You decide to explore further within the temple.")
                # Additional exploration code can be added here
                # Maze navigation
                print("After walking through dark corridors and solving intricate puzzles, you find yourself in front of a maze.")
                print("You must navigate through the maze to reach the other side.")
                maze = [
                    "##########",
                    "#    #   #",
                    "###  #   #",
                    "#    #####",
                    "###      #",
                    "##########"
                ]
                def print_maze(maze):
                    for row in maze:
                        print(row)

                print_maze(maze)

                print("Navigate through the maze using 'w' to move up, 'a' to move left, 's' to move down, and 'd' to move right.")

                current_position = [1, 1]
                while maze[current_position[0]][current_position[1]] != "#":
                    move = input("Enter your move (w/a/s/d): ")

                    if move == "w":
                        if maze[current_position[0] - 1][current_position[1]] != "#":
                            current_position[0] -= 1
                    elif move == "a":
                        if maze[current_position[0]][current_position[1] - 1] != "#":
                            current_position[1] -= 1
                    elif move == "s":
                        if maze[current_position[0] + 1][current_position[1]] != "#":
                            current_position[0] += 1
                    elif move == "d":
                        if maze[current_position[0]][current_position[1] + 1] != "#":
                            current_position[1] += 1

                    print_maze(maze)

                print("Congratulations! You have navigated through the maze and reached the other side.")
                # Final puzzle and Java Crown
                print("You have now entered a hidden secret room within the temple. Among a few statues, there is a mysterious box hanging from above.")
                print("You need to solve the final puzzle to reveal the contents of the box and claim the Java Crown.")

                final_puzzle = input("Final puzzle: What is always in front of you but can't be seen? ")

                if final_puzzle.lower() == "future":
                    print("Congratulations! You have solved the final puzzle.")
                    print("As you solve the puzzle, the box opens and from within it descends the Java Crown!")
                    print("Thank you for playing. You have successfully found the Java Crown and completed the adventure.")
                else:
                    print("Incorrect answer. The box remains closed. You need to solve the final puzzle to reveal the Java Crown.")
              else:
                # Code for opening the door
                print("You have chosen to open the large door.")
                print("As you open the door, you discover a maze-like passage ahead.")
                print("You must now find your way through the maze to progress further.")
                # Additional code for maze navigation can be added here as shown above
                # End of the game for this path
                print("Thank you for playing. The adventure ends here.")
            elif keyPath.lower() == "right":
                # Puzzles to get the key when going right
                print("You have chosen to go right. A maze appears in front of you. Navigate through the maze to get the key!")
              else:
                print("Invalid choice for the key path.")

    else:
        print("You have chosen to not enter the temple.")
else:
    print("I'm sorry, but that is an Invalid choice. Please try again!")
```

Here are the problems:
[Image-Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69bCw.png)

Mainly, like I said before, I'm trying to work on a Python project. I need to finish this today and I was finishing it up until I received these errors. I've tried changing some of the things and the things mentioned in the problem tab.

Comment: Correct Identation is important in python, most of your error statements seem to indicate that yours is wrong

Comment: It looks like it's all indentation and statement errors, you should learn about python syntax in detail first.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is returning both indentation errors, and control flow related errors. Luckily, both of these are quick to fix.

### Indentation Errors

---

Errors for python indentation problems can come about in a couple different ways. They may come up when an indented block is expected, but does not appear.

For instance, around line 95, you write:

```
...

        if move == "w":
            if maze[current_position[0]] - 1: #Python expected a block after this line!
        elif move == "a":
            if maze[current_position[0]][current_position[1] - 1] != "#":
                current_position[1] -= 1
...
```

The `if` statement with a comment next to it does not have anything inside it, and so Python errors.

It is also worth noting that you switch between using 4 spaces as indents, and 2 paces as indents. It is important for readability to stick to a single indent style. While some style guides recommend 2, it is common practice to use 4 spaces.

A similar problem occurs around line 145, where an `if` statement suddenly jumps 3 tabs in, only for future lines to be indented backwards. Use a single, 4 space indent when needed.

### Control Flow errors

---

For the `elif` problems, you are using `elif` after `else` checks multiple times throughout your snippet. In short `else` statements need to come last in the control flow, and `elif` needs to come after an `if`.  See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html for the official documentation on the subject.

For example, the outermost statement is structured:

```
if ...   #Line 25- Starting with an if is correct!
    #code
else ... #Line 121- #else has to be last
    #code
elif ... #Line 130- #elif has to be before the else
    #code
else ... #Line 133- #else has to be last
    #code
else ... #Line 137- #else has to be last
    #code
elif ... #Line 146-  #elif has to be before the else
    #code
else ... #Line 250- Ending with an else is correct!
    #code
```

on line 25, an `if` occurs, then on 121, it gets an `else`, then on 130 it gets an `elif`, 133 it gets another `else`, 137 it gets another `else` (and a missing indent), 146 it gets a `elif`, and an else on `250`.

Fixing the control flow keywords and indents will fix your errors.

Comment: Im sorry, but i dont understand what you are trying to say. Ive tried to edit the indentations, but still. Errors. @Jonathan F.

Comment: If you have already fixed the indentation errors, I would suggest reading the python documentation on how to use if/elif/else statements, and applying what it says to your code. Beyond that, what is it specifically that you are stuck on?